# How can i parse through a json file in a bash script?

Tags: json, bash, parsing

I want to grab the faceRectangle and and place that into another text file 
like so

SET "faceRectangle" ""top": 114"

SET "faceRectangle" ""left": 212"

So that all the values under there corresponding heading are properly formatted and copied into another file like above
and i want to do this in a bash file

```
[
  {
"faceRectangle": {
  "top": 114,
  "left": 212,
  "width": 65,
  "height": 65
},
"scores": {
  "anger": 1.0570484E-08,
  "contempt": 1.52679547E-09,
  "disgust": 1.60232943E-07,
  "fear": 6.00660363E-12,
  "happiness": 0.9999998,
  "neutral": 9.449728E-09,
  "sadness": 1.23025981E-08,
  "surprise": 9.91396E-10
}
 }
```

]

how would I go about doing this?

UPDATE: this is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

faceR=($(jq -r '.[0].faceRectangle' emotion.json))
scores=($(jq -r '.[0].scores' emotion.json))

echo " SET "faceRectangle" "${faceR[@]}" " >> data.txt

cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

I keep getting an error "unbalanced quotes in request"
how can I fix that?

Comment: Have a look at `jq`, the "Command-line JSON processor".

Comment: ya i have started using that but still a little stuck

Comment: Just post what you have then, along with a description of what's wrong with it.

Comment: ok i have done it

Comment: i have updated it again, i got a little further

Answer (score 0):

This ouputs what you were going for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

top=($(jq -r ".[0].faceRectangle.top" emotion.json))
left=($(jq -r ".[0].faceRectangle.left" emotion.json))

echo "SET \"faceRectangle\" \"top\": ${top}\""
echo "SET \"faceRectangle\" \"left\": ${left}\""
```